# rust-analyzer doesn't show errors and suggestions neovim

Tags: neovim, pyright, rust-analyzer, nvim-lspconfig

I have updated my arch setup and compiled neovim 0.9.1 on just installed Debian 12.

rust-analyzer doesn't show any messages and doesn't give any autocomplete suggestions.

rust-analyzer is installed by mason, by rustup component add and by npm install.

I also have added it to the PATH so there is no errors in it.

As i understand it runs (because it doesn't throw any errors) but it just ignores the file content.

This is part of my config which is related to the issue.

```lua
vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]
require("packer").startup(function(use)
  use "wbthompson/packer.nvim"
  use "vim-airline/vim-airline"
  use 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
  use 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
  use 'jpalardy/vim-slime'
  use 'shime/vim-livedown'
  use 'ap/vim-css-color'
  use 'terryma/vim-multiple-cursors'
  use 'mattn/emmet-vim'
  use 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
  use 'pacha/vem-tabline'
-- LSP
  use {
    'VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim',
    requires = {
      -- LSP Support
      {'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'},
      {'williamboman/mason.nvim'},
      {'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim'},

      -- Autocompletion
      {'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'},
      {'hrsh7th/cmp-buffer'},
      {'hrsh7th/cmp-path'},
      {'saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip'},
      {'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp'},
      {'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lua'},
      {'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp-signature-help'},
      {'hrsh7th/cmp-vsnip'},
      {'hrsh7th/vim-vsnip'},

      -- Snippets
      {'L3MON4D3/LuaSnip'},
      {'rafamadriz/friendly-snippets'},
    },
    config = function ()
      require('mason.settings').set({
        log_level = vim.log.levels.DEBUG
      })
    end
  }
end)

require([[lspconfig]]).rust_analyzer.setup({
  on_attach = function (client, buff)
    print([[rust_analyzer is attached]])
  end,
  flags = {
    debounce_text_changes = 150
  },
  cmd = {
    [[rustup]],
    [[run]],
    [[stable]],
    [[rust-analyzer]],
    --    vim.env.HOME .. '/.cargo/bin/rust_analyzer'
  }
})
```

I have tried to install rust-tools and coc.nvim.
rust-tools bringed no changes.
coc.nvim didn't respond at all.

I also tried to install package as it helped me here [neovim's lsp does not show error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74166479/neovims-lsp-does-not-show-error-messages) but it didn't help

If you need more info about my config here is the last I used before this issue https://github.com/onemorebruh/configs/tree/master/nvim

**UPD: pyright doesn't work as i expect it too**

Answer (score 2):

well i just deleted the previous project. did `cargo new project_name` and now it works. sorry for bothering.

the same with pyright. i just did git clone and lsp started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue - rust-analyzer did work, except for warnings/diagnostics.

After reading your own answer and wondering why re'loading the project helps, I did run

```bash
cargo clean
```

... and it worked again.